# Access another methods sender

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uialertview, sender

So I'm pretty new to Objective-C and kind of just learning as I go here. So I have a method that passes on its sender when called to another method. So when called internally I can call it like this:

```
[self insertNewDBInfoConnection:sender];
```

Here's where I hit a bump in the road. this insertNewDBInfoConnection: is only going to be called when the user selects an option in an alert view which is set up like so:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if([alertView.title isEqualToString:@"Would you like to save?"]) {
            switch(buttonIndex) {
                    case 0:
                            [self insertNewDBInfoConnection:sender];
                            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

                            break;

                    case 1:
                            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

                            break;
            }
    }
```

}

So ofcourse I can't just call **[self insertNewDBInfoConnection:sender];** anymore because it doesn't know what sender is. So how to do I again access that methods sender externally here. A very simple solution I'm sure, but again, learning as I go.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does insertNewDBInfoConnection use "sender" for? Can you post the code for that function?

Comment: what is "sender" where did it come from? You are going to have to provide more code to get a complete answer

Comment: you will have to take the data you need to perform the request and pass it along. you should not assume `sender` will be around when your alert is dismissed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response guys. I would post more detailed code but Justin's advice was just what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.